# Hide Console Application icon in taskbar

Tags: c#, console-application, hide, taskbar

I'm creating a Console Application, and have need of just hiding the taskbar icon, but I need to keep the window open and running.

Because it is a Console application, I can't do things like `this.ShowInTaskbar`, and `Console` or `Environment` have no methods for such either

Any ideas how to make such work?

Comment: You can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application#3571628, or set the program from `ConsoleApplication` to `WindowsApplication` and it won't show any window/console.

Comment: that's shows or hides the window. I need to hide the ICON, not the window

Comment: Ah, I misread, thats more complicated, maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243588/c-sharp-hiding-an-application-from-the-taskbar, or this: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/275936-icon-hide-taskbar-alt-tab-key (It's actually the same thing but in stackoverflow is explained)